# How can I link a registered user from django-registration to the model of my app?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-registration

I plugged the `django-registration` app into my project and it works great. New Users can register and log in. In my app, however, I want to supply a whole profile to the user and use the information which I got through `django-registration`.

**How can I connect the information from django-registration and the user model of my own app?**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import models as  auth_models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class User(User):

    username = auth_models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = auth_models.TextField()
    picture = auth_models.ImageField(upload_to=something, blank=True, null=True) 
    location = auth_models.CharField(max_length=200) # please replace with GIS API

    email = auth_models.EmailField()
    password = auth_models.CharField(max_length=128)

    # during registration: did the user click
    # the sent activiation link?
    is_active = auth_models.BooleanField(default=False)
    appear_in_public_ranking = auth_models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.username
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Django 1.5, [extending the existing User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) has been introduced. You can use this directly to add new fields.

But if you are using a previous version of Django, then do the following:

Create a new model called `Profile` and put all your required fields there.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ...
```

Then in your settings file, add:

```
AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = '<application_name>.Profile'
```

where application_name is the name of app in which you've created `Profile` model.

When you have a signed in user, you can use `request.user.get_profile()` to fetch the corresponding Profile object.